# Most different combinations of letters

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have $4$ letters (A,T,C,G). I make a sequence of $10$ letters yielding $4^{10}$ possible combinations. Out of these combinations, what is the maximum number of $10$ letter sequences that will be completely different from each other (i.e. Hamming distance $= 10$)?

Edit:
After @lulu pointed out you only have 4 combinations with a hamming distance of $10$, I would like to know what hamming distance do you need to get as close to $1536$ allowed combinations.

Comment: Do you mean pairs of sequences? To find the Hamming distance you need two sequences.

Comment: Is it not $4$?  After the third, the coordinates of the fourth are entirely determined (unless I misremember what Hamming distance is).

Comment: I think the answer is $3^{10}$. For two sequences to have no common letters in the same position, in the first position there are $4-1$ letters remaining for the second combination, and so on for the second, third up to $10$th position.

Comment: @lulu The [Hamming distance](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) between two strings is the number of positions at which the corresponding symbols are different.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig  Well, that's what I thought.  So the answer is $4$, yes?  (I am just waking up so astonishing blunders are possible).

Comment: @lulu I want the maximum number so you would remove homopolymers first (i.e. AAAAAAAAAA). Otherwise you would only have $4$, which is not what I want.

Comment: I don't understand the point of that comment.  If you give me any three strings that pass your test, then I know all the entries of the fourth and there can be no fifth.  If I am misunderstanding the condition (definitely possible) then could you give me an example of five length $2$ sequences that pass your test?  In my view the max should be $4$ regardless of the length.

Comment: My argument is very simple.  To phrase it (slightly) differently, suppose you had a list of five such.  Two of your list must have the same first entry!  Those two can not have maximal hamming distance from each other, a contradiction.

Comment: Ah yes you are correct. I'm not thinking about this correctly. Let me rephrase the question slightly.